# TFS2013 Web Access - Configuration for Stakeholders

Tags: tfs, configuration, tfs-web-access

We use TFS2013 on premise. A request came up that when using Web Access, some members with *Stakeholder* access should only have limited rights when opening work items.

They should be able to edit Description, Acceptance Criteria, etc fields, but others should be read-only, such as Iteration, State, etc.

The only option I saw was about tags *Create tag definition* option under 
*Security >> Permissions*, but that's not enough for me.

One idea was [Customizing a process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx), but this seems to be thin ice as our team doesn't have any experience with it and the [things to avoid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danhellem/archive/2013/11/14/things-to-avoid-when-customizing-tfs-work-items.aspx) list is quite long.

The best workaround approach so far is to reference the TFS ClientLibrary from *Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\* and create a custom website which implements only the required features (for example when opening a work item, State would be a Label instead of a DropDownList).

The drawback of this solution is that it would keep the whole WebAccess portal hidden, including its nice features.

So my question in short: is there a way to make certain fields read-only on the work item form for stakeholder members?

**UPDATE**
Eventually I went towards Template Customization using TFS Power Tools 2013. Now I have to following problem:
Applying rules for certain fields work just fine, but in case the field type is *TreePath*, saving the template gives the following error

> TF26062: Rule '< READONLY for="[Global]\Stakeholders" />' is not
>   supported for the field 'System.AreaPath'.
>
> There were validation errors. Continuing to save may cause the file to
>   become unloadable, do you want to continue?

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2360a6a-d274-4753-a187-e7580e63dd04/tf26062why?forum=tfsprocess) answer from 2009: *"there are some particular fields which can't be applied rules for"*

Any suggestions how to go on?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the work item types to make some fields read only.

You will never need to be careful to not mark field read only that are needed for adding items. That would include area and iteration. Use witadmin.exe to export the desired work item and add read only clauses only for those in the stakeholder group.

You would be better with a permissive model. Allow everything and tell them what bout to change. Then have an alert for changes to those fields by stakeholders.

Comment: I tried it, but I did not succeed completely. I updated the question to reflect the new issue